# How to keep track of vm hosts and guests and IP addresses?

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-server, puppet

Internally, we have several VM hosts.  We are constantly provisioning new guests on these hosts.  What tool to you guys use to keep track of what hosts hosts you have out there, the host system stats, what guests you have on those hosts, notes about what applications are running on the guests, and it'd be nice to see what virtual IPs are listed on each guest, and be able to track it back to the host?

We use VMWare

Comment: Various suggestions I gathered from IRC:  mcollective + puppetdashboard.  vcenter.

Answer (score 1):

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org)

or

[Racktables](http://racktables.org/)

Answer (score 1):

some people create a nic virtual net which identified the host from within the guest.
if you would use kvm, then there is a virt-serial which allows the guest and host to communicate.

once the guest knows its hypervisor, you could use standard inventory tools (facter, mcollective/foreman) to use that data.

Answer (score 1):

Powercli, you can find vmware powercli forum very useful and will do most of your work and your questions answered quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Also look into [Puppet's new inventory service](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/inventory_service.html).  I've not used it myself yet, but it may do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use a spreadsheet and a Sharepoint document library to track basic information regarding virtual hosts and guests.

I use Veeam Monitor for tracking VMware host stats and performance.

I use SolarWinds IP Address Tracker for tracking ip information for all computer and servers, both physical and virtual.